# How to get every value in Json by key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am making a rest call to a webservice. In its body it contains a Json file with 18 pairs key, value.

I which to make separate operations on each element so i would like to:

- get the different key elements. so i would have an array of the key elements.
- With each of those elements, get the corresponding value by dot walking.

Here is what I have:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(request.body.dataString);

var myKeys = Object.keys(obj)

for (var i = 0; i < myKeys.length; i++){

   var iter = myKeys[i];

   gs.log(obj.iter);
}
```

But the gs.log returns undefined.

I have tried to make this:

```
gs.log(obj.myId);
```

and it returns the value i want, since myId is one of the elements in keys.

How can i use the elements of my keys array to get the corresponding values?

I have confirmed that hte var myKeys has all the elements of keys and the var obj contains all the json file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: What is `gs.log`? What is `.iter`? What do you expect? Can you show some sample JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `[]` syntax.

```
var iter = myKeys[i];

gs.log(obj[iter]);
```

Plain `obj.iter` tries to get a property called literally `iter`. If you want to get a property based on the string value of the variable `iter`, you need to access the object using `obj[iter]`.